# Applying changes to outer Monads in Haskell without using Transformer monads

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monads, monad-transformers, state-monad

I am trying to do something like the following where I want to return an error message in case the state of a State-Monad isn't fulfilling a certain condition, can it be done without using `lift` and `ExceptT` or other transformer monad?

```
type Log = State [String] ()

stateCheckDuplicate :: String -> Either String Log
stateCheckDuplicate elem = 
  Right (do 
    log <- get
    if lookup elem log /= Nothing then Left "Duplicate elements"
    else    
      (put (elem:log)))
```

Comment: The type `Either String Log` isomorphic to the type `Either String ([String] -> [String])`,  it is a string or a string list modifier function. How do you write a string list modifier function in terms of errors? There is no way.

Comment: I am not sure I understand. Why couldn't you write a string list modifier function in terms of error? Couldnt you just have it return `Either String [String]` I guess this isn't more of a problem than `Either String Int` or any other types using `Either` ! Or am I wrong here?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid transformers? (I suspect if you try, you will end up reinventing transformers...)

Comment: @DanielWagner , I want (or wanted) to avoid transformers for two reasons. First I was not sure if they were the best approach, and hence I wanted to ask in here if some of you were aware of something that I yet didn't even know about, or didn't even suspect existed. Second I wanted to avoid them since I am solving an exercise in which I am still not sure of whether I can use the transformer monad without breaking some existing types in the *outer* function which should contain the `stateCheckDuplicate`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand what the `stateCheckDuplicate` should do, you need the type of `stateCheckDuplicate` isomorphic to `String -> [String] -> Either String [String]`. Then your implementation will look like this:

```
stateCheckDuplicate :: String -> [String] -> Either String [String]
stateCheckDuplicate msg logs
    | msg `elem` logs = Left "Duplicate elements"
    | otherwise       = Right $ msg : logs
```

As you can see, there is nor State, nor ExceptT, nor liftXXX. But maybe there is one problem, this function is "hard" to compose with others functions. To solve this problem need understand what you try to do.

---

Update on:

> Ok, so I want to use it for a sequence of operations within a do-block, such that the state (or in this case string) will be updated at every operation. Each of these operations could then in turn be handled using for instance mapM_ or the like. I want the function with this do-block to return the Left "Duplicate elements" if the State or String-function returns the Left part, otherwise the function with the do block shall return a completely other type, that could be Either String (Int, Int) or something else.

For using this operation in do-block, the result type should be an instanca of class `Monad`. You can make your own type for this purpose.

```
newtype LogM a = LogM { runLogM :: [String] -> (Either String a, [String]) }

instance Functor LogM where
    fmap f m = LogM $ \log0 ->
        let (ex, log1) = runLogM m log0 in
        case ex of
            Right x  -> (Right $ f x, log1)
            Left err -> (Left err, log1)

instance Applicative LogM where
    pure x = LogM $ \log -> (Right x, log)
    mf <*> mx = do
        f <- mf
        x <- mx
        pure $ f x

instance Monad LogM where
    m >>= k = LogM $ \log0 ->
        let (ex, log1) = runLogM m log0 in
        case ex of
            Right x  -> runLogM (k x) log1
            Left err -> (Left err, log1)

instance MonadState [String] LogM where
    state f = LogM $ \log0 ->
        let (x, log1) = f log0 in
        (Right x, log1)

instance MonadError String LogM where
    throwError err = LogM $ \log -> (Left err, log)
    catchError m h = LogM $ \log0 ->
        let (ex, log1) = runLogM m log0 in
        case ex of
            Right x  -> (Right x, log1)
            Left err -> runLogM (h err) log1

stateCheckDuplicate :: String -> LogM ()
stateCheckDuplicate msg = do
    log <- get
    if msg `elem` log then
        throwError "Duplicate elements"
    else
        put $ msg : log
```

But compare how easy it will be with transformers:

```
type LogM = ExceptT String (State [String])

stateCheckDuplicate :: String -> LogM ()
stateCheckDuplicate msg = do
    log <- get
    if msg `elem` log then
        throwError "Duplicate elements"
    else
        put $ msg : log
```

If you don't want type alias you can do like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-} 

newtype LogM a = LogM { runLogM :: ExceptT String (State [String]) a }
    deriving ( Functor, Applicative, Monad
             , MonadState [String]
             , MonadError String
             )
```

Comment: Ok, so I want to use it for a sequence of operations within a `do`-block, such that the state (or in this case string) will be updated at every operation. Each of these operations could then in turn be handled using for instance `mapM_` or the like. I want the function with this `do`-block to return the `Left "Duplicate elements"` if the State or String-function returns the `Left` part, otherwise the function with the do block shall return a completely other type, that could be `Either String (Int, Int)` or something else.

Comment: @Piskator That is *exactly* what combining state and exceptions using monad transformers gets you.

Comment: nicely done. I suspect this is what @DanielWagner points to when he warns about 'recreating' transformers from the bottom. So I see your point of taking the short cut of using the transformers. Although as I have just commented in the original post, it was not clear to begin with, whether it was the right approach.